# Is this javascript code that uses Ramda.js looks ok?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

This code works but I have no idea whether it looks OK and whether ramda.js was used properly. Does it look functional and readable?

I also use Q for promises.

readDir reads all files in directory including statistics,
        this function is used in other places as well

What do you think?

```
 function readDir(p) {

        return R.pipeP(
            function() {
                return fs.readdir(p);
            },
            R.map(function(file) {

                 return fs.stat(path.join(p, file))
                    .then(function(stats) {

                        return {
                            file: file,
                            stats: stats,
                            fullfilename: path.join(p, file)
                        };
                    })
                    .fail(function(err){
                        log.error(err);
                    });
            }), Q.all
        );
    }



//delete last, filter using statistics
function deleteFilesExceptOne(folder) {

        return R.pipeP(
            function() {
                return readDir(folder)();
            },
            R.filter(function(fl) {
                return (fl.stats.isFile() &&  timespan.fromDates(fl.stats.mtime, new Date()).totalSeconds() > 120);


            }),
            R.tail,
            R.map(function(fl) {

                return fs.unlink(fl.fullfilename);
            }),
            Q.all
        );
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: If this is working code that you want to get feedback on, you might consider posting on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks, i am new here.  will try there.

Comment: This actually belongs to codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm one of the authors of Ramda, I don't use `pipeP` much, preferring `Future`/`Task` implementations to `Promises`, so I'm perhaps not the best person to answer this.  But I would definitely suggest that this is not the most idiomatic way that one might use Ramda.  Here is an entirely untested version of your second function, with several helper functions broken out:

```
var isFile = function(file) {
    return file.stats.isFile();
};

var olderThan = R.curry(function(seconds, file) {
    return timespan.fromDates(file.stats.mtime, new Date()).totalSeconds() > seconds;
});

var deleteFilesExceptOne = R.pipeP(
    readDir,
    R.filter(R.both(isFile, olderThan(120))),
    R.tail,
    R.map(R.pipe(R.prop('fullfilename'), fs.unlink)),
    Q.all
);
```

Note especially the change from this:

```
function deleteFilesExceptOne(folder) {
    return R.pipeP(
        function() {
            return readDir(folder)();
        },
        //...
```

to this:

```
var deleteFilesExceptOne = R.pipeP(
    readDir,
    // ...
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there is some useful clean-up still to be done in `olderThan`.

And as I said, none of this is tested.

Comment: Thank you . Looks much better now. Do you think Promises implementation  will look better then pipe?